# No such module 'Alamofire' when i try Archive app

Tags: swift3, alamofire

When i run the app i haven´t any problem.

But when i try archive for deploy app i have this error "No such module 'Alamofire'" in specific class.

I tried clean and build project, and i don´t have any problem.

My pod file like this

```
platform :ios '9.0'
use_frameworks!
target 'app_name' do
   pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
   pod 'PayPal-iOS-SDK', '~> 2.12.0'
   pod 'moa', '~> 8.0'
   pod 'Auk', '~> 7.0'
   pod 'AZSClient'
end
```

What might be happening?

Comment: Just re check embedded binaries section and linked frameworks and libraries..make sure it adds correctly pods_yourprojectname.framework

Comment: @AnilKukadeja, i have "Alamofire" in Embedded Binaries and in Linked Framworks and Libraries

Answer (score 0):

Clear your **DerivedData** then clean and build your project.

To clear Derived Data:

> 1. Goto xcode preferences or press **⌘,**
> 2. Then select **Locations** option
> 3. Click on the arrow showing near the *DerivedData* path, it will open *DerivedData* folder.
> 4. Select all folders and files (⌘A) inside the *DerivedData* folder and delete(⌘Del).

Comment: The error continues, however, even now when I build.

Comment: What the solution you @HideCode got for this, i am also have this issue. Please tell any one.... who should find the solution for this..!